# Angular factory success and error callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've set a factory with callback for success and error. However when I use it in the controller I need to alway define both success and error functions if I don't define a error callback function, it won't work.

Is there anyways that could make error callback optional when it needs to be use.

Controller

```
$scope.saveUsername = function(){
    atFactory.saveUsername($scope, function(){
        // this is success
    }, function(){
        // this is error
    });
}
```

Factory

```
at.factory('atFactory', ['$http' , function ( $http ){
    var factory = {};

    factory.saveUsername = function($scope,callback){
        $scope.url = '/member/username';
        $scope.post_data = { 
            username : $scope.username
        };
        factory.doPostHttpRequest($scope).success(callback).error(callback);
    }   

    factory.doPostHttpRequest = function($scope){
        return $http({
            url : $scope.url,
            method: 'POST', 
            data: $scope.post_data
        })
    }

    return factory;

}]);
```

Comment: It will work, except you will not know when an error came.

Comment: try to do it like this

`return factory.doPostHttpRequest($scope)` instead of ` factory.doPostHttpRequest($scope).success(callback).error(callback);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion to you is to return the `$http` promise back to the controller, then you can call the `success()` in your controller (and optionally `error()`).

So in your factory:

```
factory.saveUsername = function($scope){
    $scope.url = '/member/username';
    $scope.post_data = { 
        username : $scope.username
    };
    return factory.doPostHttpRequest($scope);
}

factory.doPostHttpRequest = function($scope){
    return $http({
        url : $scope.url,
        method: 'POST', 
        data: $scope.post_data
    })
}
```

Then in your controller, you can do:

```
atFactory.saveUsername($scope)
.success(function(response) {
    // success callback (optional)
})
.error(function(error) {
    // error callback (optional)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
at.factory('atFactory', ['$http' , function ( $http ){
        var factory = {};

        factory.saveUsername = function($scope,successCallBack, errorCallBack){
            $scope.url = '/member/username';
            $scope.post_data = { 
                username : $scope.username
            };
            return factory.doPostHttpRequest($scope).success(function(){
               if(successCallBack){
                   successCallBack();
               }
           }).error(function(){
               if(errorCallBack){
                   errorCallBack();
               }
            });
        }   

        factory.doPostHttpRequest = function($scope){
            return $http({
                url : $scope.url,
                method: 'POST', 
                data: $scope.post_data
            })
        }

        return factory;

    }]);
```